# I am call this REST API from AJAX but somehow not able to pass JSON object to @Path("/putEmp")?

Tags: json, ajax, rest

JSON passing to REST API in Java either in GET or PUT way, what are the libs I should have other than the following?

1. bson-3.0.1.jar

   2. jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
   3. jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
2. jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
   jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar 
          jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar

   jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar
   jersey-entity-filtering-2.17.jar  jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17.jar
   json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar

Still I am getting the following error when I access this REST Service:

EROOR:  No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

```
    @GET
    @Path("/getJSON2/{a}/{b}/{c}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject getJSON2(@PathParam ("a") int a, @PathParam ("b") String b, @PathParam ("c") String c) throws JSONException
    {
    JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
    Employee ee = new Employee();
    ee.setId(a);
    ee.setFname(b);
    ee.setLName(c);
    System.out.println("==========="+ee.toString());
    js.put("employee", ee);
    return js;
}
```